# How to get all the strings after a specific index?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this string: `/ban 1d hello world` which is essentially a command sended to a bot, meaning:

- `/ban` specify to ban the user
- `1d` represents the time
- `hello world` is the reason

I need to get the `reason`, so I did:

```js
let c = '/ban 1d hello world';
let arr = c.split(' ');
let result = c.replace(arr[0], '');
result = result.replace(arr[1], '')
alert(result);
```

this is working, but I would like to ask if there is a better way to achieve this.

Kind regards.

Comment: You should also read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know that your reason will always be after the second space, you can do something like:

```
const c = '/ban 1d hello world';
const reason = c.split(' ').slice(2).join(' ');
```

Comment: +1 It might also be good to extend this idea of yours into a list of API commands, each command with its parameters defined, etc. mostly for differentiating between multi-word parameters from single-word ones.

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is a good way to match a known format.
You can match against a slash `\/` followed by two words separated by spaces `\S+ \S+` and then match the remaining characters `(.*)`.

```js
let c = '/ban 1d hello world';
let match = /\/\S+ \S+ (.*)/.exec(c);
let result = match[1];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the concrete format of the command parts, you could use a regex to get each individual part this way:

```js
let c = '/ban 1d hello world';

var regex = /\/([a-z]+)\ ([0-9]+[a-z])\ (.*)/g;
var resultArray = regex.exec(c);

console.log(resultArray);

let command = resultArray[1] //ban
let time = resultArray[2]; //1d
let result = resultArray[3]; //hello world

console.log(result);
```